# Why $\limsup_{n\to \infty }\mathbb P(X_n\leq x)\leq \limsup_{n\to \infty }\mathbb E[g_{x,\varepsilon }(X_n)]$?

Tags: probability

Let $(X_n)$ a stochastic process on a probability space $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$. Let $$g_{x,\varepsilon }(y)=\begin{cases}1&y\leq x\\ 0&x\geq x+\varepsilon \\ linear
&x\leq y\leq x+\varepsilon .\end{cases}$$

Then, in my course, is written that $$\limsup_{n\to \infty }\mathbb P(X_n\leq x)\leq \limsup_{n\to \infty }\mathbb E[g_{x,\varepsilon }(X_n)]$$ but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

Simply because $$g_{x,\varepsilon }(X_n)=\boldsymbol 1_{\{X_n\leq x\}}+g_{x,\varepsilon }(X_n)\boldsymbol 1_{\{x\leq X_n\leq x+\varepsilon \}}\geq \boldsymbol 1_{\{X_n\leq x\}}.$$